# Nightwatch's exit code is 0 when a suite's beforeEach times out

Tags: nightwatch.js

Here's the minimal example:

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(browser, done) {
  },
  'Actual Test': function() {
  },
};
```

And here's the output:

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  91910

[Timeout] Test Suite
========================

 _________________________________________________

 TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution,  0 assertions failed, 0 passed. (10.09s)

 ✖ timeout

   done() callback timeout of 10000 ms was reached while executing "before". Make sure to call the done() callback when the operation finishes.

   SKIPPED:
   - Actual Test
```

But the exit code is 0, not 1

```
$ echo $?
0
```

I expect the exit code to be 1 so I can detect test failure. Is there a way to make the exit code non-zero?

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch expects to have `done()` callback in `before()` method:

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(browser, done) {
     ...some initialization...
     done();  // <--- here
  }
};
```

Technically your tests are passed (0 failed from 0 tests), it's just an incorrect flow management and probably Nightwatch should treat such issues as error an return 1. 
I believe in most cases you would like to catch some actual test failures and in that case you should add some real assert and if it's fails then you will get exit code 1:

```
module.exports = {
  before: function(browser, done) {
      done();
  },
  'Actual Test': function(browser) {
      browser.url('http://somewhere.com');
      browser.assert.urlEquals('http://www.google.com');  // <-- test fails with return status code 1
  }
};
```